# Git and a hard reset

Tags: git, github

I have been working on my dev branch for sooo long that nothing in my master is relevant.  I would like to totally wipe master clean so I can merge my dev branch in master with a clean slate.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just delete master and rename your branch to master assuming this is not shared

Answer (score 0):

You can make master be the exact copy of dev by doing the following:

```
git checkout dev
git push origin dev:master
```